# Update JS model through MVC not change

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

i have variables as a model, i were able to change it temporary but when try to update other values it's fetched in the controller but when try to re render it again it show the new value and retrieve the old value quickly,

the issue in updateCat func i think, also i want to pass form is object not each value alone as updated-name and updated-img.

Thanks in advance.

```js
/* ======= Model ======= */

var model = {
    currentCat: null,
    cats: [
        {
            clickCount: 0,
            name: 'Tabby',
            imgSrc: 'img/434164568_fea0ad4013_z.jpg',
            imgAttribution: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/bigtallguy/434164568',
            isAdmin: 0
        },
        {
            clickCount: 0,
            name: 'Tiger',
            imgSrc: 'img/4154543904_6e2428c421_z.jpg',
            imgAttribution: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/xshamx/4154543904',
            isAdmin: 0
        },
        {
            clickCount: 0,
            name: 'Scaredy',
            imgSrc: 'img/22252709_010df3379e_z.jpg',
            imgAttribution: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/kpjas/22252709',
            isAdmin: 0
        },
        {
            clickCount: 0,
            name: 'Shadow',
            imgSrc: 'img/1413379559_412a540d29_z.jpg',
            imgAttribution: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/malfet/1413379559',
            isAdmin: 0
        },
        {
            clickCount: 0,
            name: 'Sleepy',
            imgSrc: 'img/9648464288_2516b35537_z.jpg',
            imgAttribution: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/onesharp/9648464288',
            isAdmin: 0
        }
    ]
};


/* ======= Octopus ======= */

var octopus = {

    init: function () {
        // set our current cat to the first one in the list
        model.currentCat = model.cats[0];

        // tell our views to initialize
        catViewList.init();
        catView.init();
    },

    getCurrentCat: function () {
        return model.currentCat;
    },

    getCats: function () {
        return model.cats;
    },

    // set the currently-selected cat to the object passed in
    setCurrentCat: function (cat) {
        model.currentCat = cat;
    },

    // increments the counter for the currently-selected cat
    incrementCounter: function () {
        model.currentCat.clickCount++;
        catView.render();
    },

    // Admin mode, to edit exist cat (name, url)
    showAdminForm: function () {
        model.currentCat.isAdmin = 1;
        catView.render();
    },

    updateCat: function (name, img) {
        console.log(name + " ----- " + img + " before currentCat " + model.currentCat.name);
        model.currentCat.name = name;
        model.currentCat.imgSrc = img;

        catView.render();
    }
};


/* ======= View ======= */
var catView = {

    init: function () {
        // POINTERS
        this.catElem = document.getElementById('cat-div');
        this.catNameElem = document.getElementById('cat-name');
        this.catCounter = document.getElementById('cat-counter');
        this.catImage = document.getElementById('cat-image');
        this.isAdmin = document.getElementById('show-admin');
        this.adminPanel = document.getElementById('admin-panel');
        this.newName = document.getElementById('updated-name');
        this.newImg = document.getElementById('updated-name');

        this.isAdmin.addEventListener('click', function () {
            octopus.showAdminForm();
        });

        this.catImage.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Get count from octopus
            octopus.incrementCounter();
        });
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {

        // Empty the form
        // this.isAdmin.innerHTML = '';

        // update the DOM elements with values from the current cat         
        var currentCat = octopus.getCurrentCat();
        this.catCounter.textContent = currentCat.clickCount;
        this.catNameElem.textContent = currentCat.name;
        this.catImage.src = currentCat.imgSrc;
        this.isAdmin = currentCat.isAdmin;
        this.newName.textContent = currentCat.name;
        this.newImg.src = currentCat.imgSrc;

        this.adminPanel.addEventListener('submit', function() {
            var updatedName = document.getElementById("updated-name").value;
            var updatedImg = document.getElementById("updated-img").value;


            // document.getElementById('cat-name') = updatedName;

            
            octopus.updateCat(updatedName, updatedImg);
            // catView.render();
        });
        

        if (this.isAdmin == 1) {
            this.adminPanel.style.display = "block";
            // problem here when changed and re render it fetched old name
            // this.adminPanel.addEventListener('submit', function() {
            //     var updatedName = document.getElementById("updated-name").value;
            //     var updatedImg = document.getElementById("updated-img").value;

            //     console.log(updatedName + updatedImg);

            //     // document.getElementById('cat-name') = updatedName;

                
            //     octopus.updateCat(updatedName, updatedImg);
            //     // catView.render();
            // });
        } else {
            this.adminPanel.style.display = "none";
        }


    }
};


var catViewList = {

    init: function () {
        // store the DOM element for easy access later
        this.catListElem = document.getElementById('side_nav_item');

        // render this view (update the DOM elements with the right values)
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        var cat, elem, i;
        // get the cats we'll be rendering from the octopus
        var cats = octopus.getCats();

        // empty the cat list
        this.catListElem.innerHTML = '';

        // loop over the cats
        for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
            // this is the cat we're currently looping over
            cat = cats[i];

            // make a new cat list item and set its text
            elem = document.createElement('a');
            elem.textContent = cat.name;

            // on click, setCurrentCat and render the catView
            // (this uses our closure-in-a-loop trick to connect the value
            //  of the cat variable to the click event function)
            elem.addEventListener('click', (function (catCopy) {
                return function () {
                    octopus.setCurrentCat(catCopy);
                    catView.render();
                };
            })(cat));

            // finally, add the element to the list
            this.catListElem.appendChild(elem);
        }
    }
};



octopus.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
    <title>Cat List </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="side_nav" class="sidenav" >
            <li id="side_nav_item" class="side_nav_item"></li>
        </div>

        <div id="cat-div">
            <h2 id="cat-name"></h2>
            <div id="cat-counter"></div>
            <img id="cat-image" src="" alt="cute cat">
        </div>

        <button id="show-admin">Admin</button>

        <form id="admin-panel">
            <label >Name :</label> 
            <input type="text" id="updated-name">
            <label>Img url :</label>
            <input type="text" id="updated-img">

            <button id="updateCat" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
        
        <script src="js/model.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my silly issue,

```
this.adminPanel.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
        var nameToChange = document.getElementById('updated-name').value;
        var imgTOChange = document.getElementById('updated-img').value;
        console.log(nameToChange + imgTOChange);
        octopus.updateCat(nameToChange + imgTOChange);
        evt.preventDefault();   // Here is the trick

    });
```

to close.

Thanks.